# Scipy Wilcoxon throwing TypeError when trying to specify an alternative hypothesis

Tags: python, scipy

As the title states, when I try to specify an alternative hypothesis using the 'alternative' parameter for the `scipy.stats.wilcoxon()`function, it throws a TypeError. The TypeError states `wilcoxon() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alternative'`.

I don't encounter any issues when I specify different a different zero_method and runs as expected when I remove the 'alternative' parameter.

Scipy version 1.2.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code as simple as:

`from scipy.stats import wilcoxon
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(wilcoxon(data, alternative='greater'))`

will cause the TypeError to appear.

Comment: Please, share with us the code that is giving that error message.

Comment: Just using something as simple as:

`from scipy.stats import wilcoxon
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(wilcoxon(data, alternative='greater'))`

will cause the TypeError to occur. I've added this to the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alternative` parameter was added to [`scipy.stats.wilcoxon`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html) in SciPy 1.3.0.

Unfortunately, the addition is not mentioned in the [1.3.0 release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html).  The change is among the [pull requests for 1.3.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html#pull-requests-for-1-3-0), though.

Comment: Is there a different parameter used in `scipy.stats.wilcoxon()` for SciPy 1.2.1 to change the hypothesis testing or does it only perform a two-sided test prior to SciPy 1.3.0?